# Compatible driver motor for JGA25-370

Tags: arduino-uno, motor

I'm new to electronics so I came here to ask some questions:

1. I have four JGA25-370 motors (6 V, 58 rpm) and two L298N motor drivers. If I use one driver to control two motors, will I have maximum torque from my motors?
2. Will one 9 V battery per driver be enough? Should I use two 9 V batteries per motor driver (each driver will control two motors)?
3. I saw that my motors need 900 mA at full load, 380 mA with load, and 80 mA when idle. My driver provides 36 mA; this is less than the needs of my motors. Will it be a problem to achieve the maximum potential from my motors?

Comment: 9V batteries are a poor choice for anything that draws more than a few tens of milliamperes. (900mA is right out.)

Answer (score 0):

Yes the battery is the main problem together with an undersized motor torque. Meaning your mechanical load >>2W motor rating and must be changed to exceed Load.  Physics 101.

Stall start current is 1A and if reversed at full speed 2A surge with normal max rated load 0.2A

This motor is temperature rated for 2W MAX = V*I

Since drivers are bipolar they drop at least 1.5 to 2.5V depending on current . So if you want max torque use and voltage use 2S Li-ion cell’s with current sensing and MOSFET 2A full bridge drivers with PWM speed/ power regulation. Determine Wh capacity you need.

Specs
    6V
 58
 0.06
 50
 0.4
 2.5
 20
 2
 1.5
 103

Load speed
rpm/min 
Load currentA 
Rated torque
kg.cm 
Stall torquekgcm 
Stall currentA 
Power
W 
Reduction ratio1:00 
Gearbox long mm